# Is there an iterative way to evaluate least squares estimation?

Tags: numerical-linear-algebra, least-squares, parameter-estimation

Suppose to have a set of data $\{y_i, u_i\}_{i=1}^m$, where $y_i \in \mathbb{R}$ and $u_i \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

The claim is that

$$y_i = u_i^\top \theta + \varepsilon$$
where $\theta \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is a vector of unknown parameters and $\varepsilon$ is some kind of zero-average noise (e.g. Gaussian noise).

If I build the followings:

$$Y = \left[\begin{array}{c}y_1\\y_2\\\vdots\\y_m\end{array}\right],
U = \left[\begin{array}{c}u_1^\top\\u_2^\top\\\vdots\\u_m^\top\end{array}\right], $$

then I can find a least squares estimation of $\theta$:

$$\hat\theta = (U^\top U)^{-1}U^\top Y.$$

Anyway, suppose that $n$ and $m$ are very huge. Then solving the previous problem numerically is very hard due to memory consumption.

**My question is**: is there some iterative methods such that I can find $\hat\theta$ iteratively in order to save memory?

I hope that there exists some schema like the following:

$$\begin{align}
\hat\theta_1 & = f(y_1, u_1)\\
\hat\theta_2 & = g(\theta_1, y_2, u_2) \\
\hat\theta_3 & = g(\theta_2, y_3, u_3) \\
\vdots\\
\hat\theta_m & = g(\theta_{m-1}, y_m, u_m) = \hat\theta =  (U^\top U)^{-1}U^\top Y.\\
\end{align}$$

Comment: One thing you could do is use the conjugate gradient method to solve the normal equations. However, other iterative methods specifically designed for least squares problems are available.

Comment: @littleO can you tell me some example of these iterative methods?

Comment: There's a method called LSMR (from a paper by David Fong and Michael Saunders) that is supposed to be better than using conjugate gradient method on the normal equations. (But CG on the normal equations is simple and might work well enough for you, so I think it's a good place to start.)  Apparently LSMR is equivalent to using Minres to solve the normal equations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can apply gradient descent techniques to optimize the square loss :

$$L(\theta) = \sum_i (y_i - u_i^T\theta)^2$$

Compute the gradient $\nabla_\theta L$ and apply the gradient descent method of your choice.

The basic scheme is given by the recursion

$$\theta_{n+1} = \theta_{n} - \sigma \nabla_{\theta_n} L$$

For some stepsize $\sigma$ which should be adjusted. However this is clunky, and second order methods should be prefered, for example [Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method_in_optimization), or [LBFGS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limited-memory_BFGS) if you have a large number of variables and memory is a bottleneck, which seems to be the case.

You could also apply [stochastic gradient descent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_gradient_descent) or some variant (ADAGRAD, ADADELTA). There is extensive literature on the subject.

Comment: can you give me some links?

Comment: Newton's method would require solving the normal equations, which is the problem we're trying to solve.

Comment: I've edited the answer with links ; @littleO : hence my suggestion of LBFGS

Answer (score 3):

I recommend checking out the paper "[LSMR: An iterative algorithm for sparse least squares problems](http://arxiv.org/abs/1006.0758)" by Fong and Saunders.

This algorithm is [included in scipy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.lsmr.html).